# How can I truncate ${level} in nlog layout to a single character?

Tags: nlog

In the log I would like:

```
...D...
```

instead of

```
...Debug...
```

Same of course for Info, Warn, etc.  I have tried `${level[0]}` and other variations for the layout, no luck.

Comment: NLog ver. 4.4.6 added single-letter-option: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2034

Comment: thanks, we moved to serilog a few months later though :)

Comment: Well the feature is waiting for you, until then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

Since NLog 4.4.6 you could also do `${level:format=FirstCharacter}`. See [docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Level-Layout-Renderer)

#### Original answer

You could do it with a `${when}` which is a bit cumbersome:

e.g.

```
${when:when=level=LogLevel.Trace:inner=T:else=${when:when=level=LogLevel.Debug:inner=D:else=TODO}}
```

Or you could add a "wrapper" with some code:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Take the left characters
/// </summary>
/// <example>
/// ${left:${level}:Length=2} //[DefaultParameter]
/// ${left:Inner=${level}:Length=2} 
/// ${level:Length=2} //[ambient] 
/// </example>
[LayoutRenderer("left")]
[AmbientProperty("Left")]
[ThreadAgnostic]
public sealed class LeftLayoutRendererWrapper : WrapperLayoutRendererBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the length in characters. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>Index</value>
    /// <docgen category='Transformation Options' order='10' />
    [DefaultValue(1)]
    public int Length { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Post-processes the rendered message. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The text to be post-processed.</param>
    /// <returns>Substringed</returns>
    protected override string Transform(string text)
    {
        if (text == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (Length <= 0)
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }

        return text.Substring(0, Length);
    }
}
```

register it (as soon as possible, eg. in `main()` or `app_start()`)

```
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.LayoutRenderers
                        .RegisterDefinition("left", typeof(MyNamespace.LeftLayoutRendererWrapper ));
```

usage:

```
${left:${level}:Length=2} //or
${level:Length=2} //"ambient way"
```

Comment: Have you tried the `LeftLayoutRendererWrapper` ? I think we will include this one in NLog 4.4

Comment: I did, as I said it worked right out of the box.  If only for the ${level} case I'd say it would be great to have built-in.